# access previous site after DNS change

Tags: web, dns

because of some background issues we have to change webhosting. unfortunately after the change I have found that we did not backup one file. We have no access to ftp server or any access to previous hosting. Only available way was via http and public access.
The domain is spedimex.cz, now running on new hosting with new dns etc. I thought that if I search for previous records and try to access the site via IP address I will be able to gain desired file. 
History was gained from here
https://dnshistory.org/dns-records/spedimex.cz
but when I try to access A record 46.28.50.165 it says that page does not exits. Any tips how to access previous data?

thanks for tips!

Answer (score 0):

Use hosts file. On linux is usually at /etc/hosts.

So you write on the last line

```
46.28.50.165    spedimex.cz
```

(if I understood correctly), then go get the files, then restore the hosts file.

Comment: thanks, but for unknown reason this does not work. ping spedimex.cz goes to 46.28.50.165, but firefox show data from new hosting 46.28.105.141.

Comment: Try a new browser (or firefox later), I guess firefox cache the dns for a little time.

Comment: ff, chrome, ie all the same :(

Comment: Curious, it should work, try again later. Alternatively, try to reach support at the old host.